# Sum of the series $\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n-1}{1}+\binom{n-2}{2}-\binom{n-3}{3}+..........$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> The sum of the series $$\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n-1}{1}+\binom{n-2}{2}-\binom{n-3}{3}+..........$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $\displaystyle \binom{n}{0} = $ Coefficient of $x^0$ in $(1+x)^n$

Similarly $\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{1} = $ Coefficient of $x^1$ in $(1+x)^{n-1}$

Similarly $\displaystyle \binom{n-2}{2} = $ Coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1+x)^{n-2}$

Now, how can I solve it after that, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: Consider the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^n$

Comment: @Math It was not asked to determine $\sum \limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}$, but $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n-k}{k}$

Comment: Oops, yeah I read the question wrong. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any polynomial $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\deg f} a_k x^k$, we will use $[x^k] f(x)$ to denote $a_k$, the coefficient of $x^k$ in $f(x)$. Notice

$$\binom{n-k}{k} = [x^k](1+x)^{n-k} = [x^n] (x+x^2)^{n-k}$$

We have
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n-k}{k}\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n [x^n] (x+x^2)^{n-k}(-1)^k
= [x^n]\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (x+x^2)^{n-k}(-1)^k\right)\\
&= [x^n] \frac{(x+x^2)^{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1}}{1+x+x^2}
= [x^n] \frac{[\color{red}{\cancel{\color{gray}{(x+x^2)^{n+1}}}} + (-1)^n](1-x)}{1-x^3}\\
&= (-1)^n [x^n] \frac{1-x}{1-x^3}\\
&= (-1)^n [x^n]\left((1 - x) + x^3(1-x) + x^6(1-x) + \cdots\right)
\end{align}
$$
Based on last expression, it is clear the sum depends only on $n \pmod 6$. 
Its value is given by following formula:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}
= \begin{cases}
+1, & n \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 6\\
-1, & n \equiv 3, 4 \pmod 6\\
0, & n \equiv 2, 5 \pmod 6
\end{cases}$$

Comment: How do you get
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n-k}{k}= \sum_{k=0}^n [x^n] (x+x^2)^{n-k}(-1)^k.$$
Shouldn't it be $[x^k]$ in stead of $[x^n]$?

Comment: @Servaes $\binom{n-k}{k} = [x^k] (1+x)^{n-k} = [x^n]x^{n-k}(1+x)^{n-k} = [x^n](x+x^2)^{n-k}$.

Answer (score 9):

Denote this sum by $S_n$ then from $${n+1 \choose m} = {n \choose m} + {n \choose m-1}$$ it follows that $$S_{n+1}=S_{n}-S_{n-1}.$$ Now start from $S_0= S_1= 1$ and you will notice the pattern.

Comment: very insightful! (+1) can this method be used to solve other summation problems involving binomial coefficients?

Comment: @hypergeometric Thanks. Sure, try this sum without the alternating sign and you get another famous recursion. ;-)

Comment: The Fibonacci series! How clever :) Would this method be classified as proof by induction?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$\binom{n}{0}= \mbox{ coefficient of } x^n \mbox{ in } (1+x)^n \\
\binom{n-1}{1}= \mbox{ coefficient of } x^n \mbox{ in } x^2(1+x)^{n-1} \\
\binom{n-2}{2}= \mbox{ coefficient of } x^n \mbox{ in } x^4(1+x)^{n-2} \\
...$$

**Hint 2:**
$$(1+x)^n-x^2(1+x)^{n-1}+x^4(1+x)^{n-2}-..=(1+x)^n \left(1-(\frac{x^2}{1+x})+ (\frac{x^2}{1+x})^2-(\frac{x^2}{1+x})^3 ...\right)$$

Comment: Fantastic idea!—but needs fixing: the terms should be $(1+x)^n$, $x^2(1+x)^{n-1}$, $x^4(1-x)^{n-2}$, etc.

Comment: @GregMartin Ups, thank you, fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

**Generating Functions**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}x^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}x^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{n+k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)^n\\
&=\frac1{1-x(1-x)}\\
&=\frac1{1-x+x^2}\\
&=\frac{1+x}{1+x^3}\\[6pt]
&=(1+x)(1-x^3+x^6-x^9+\dots)\\[11pt]
&=1+x-x^3-x^4+x^6+x^7-x^9-x^{10}+\dots
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}=\left\{\begin{array}{r}
1&\text{if }n\equiv0,1\pmod6\\
0&\text{if }n\equiv2,5\pmod6\\
-1&\text{if }n\equiv3,4\pmod6
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{n \choose 0} - {n - 1 \choose 1} + {n - 2 \choose 2} -
> {n-3 \choose 3} + \cdots:\ ?}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n - k \choose k} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}{n - k \choose n - 2k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - k} \over z^{n - 2k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-\,{z^{2} \over 1 + z}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
{1 \over 1 + z^{2}/\pars{1 + z}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} \over z^{n + 1}\pars{z^{2} + z + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\,\,\,\stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\,\,\,
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{+}}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} \over z^{2} + z + 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{1 + r}^{n + 1} \over 2r + 1} +
{\pars{1 + \bar{r}}^{\, n + 1} \over 2\bar{r} + 1}\quad
\mbox{where}\quad
r \equiv -\,{1 \over 2} + {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic =
\exp\pars{{2\pi \over 3}\,\ic}
\end{align}

---

Then $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{note that}\ 1 + r = \exp\pars{{\pi \over 3}\,\ic}~}}$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n - k \choose k} & =
2\,\Re\pars{\bracks{1 + r}^{n + 1} \over 2r + 1} =
2\,\Re\pars{\expo{\bracks{n + 1}\pi\ic/3} \over \root{3}\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{{2\root{3} \over 3}
\,\sin\pars{\bracks{n + 1}\pi \over 3}} =
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{%
{\root{3} \over 3}\,\sin\pars{n\pi \over 3} + \cos\pars{n\pi \over 3}} 
\end{align}

> This result generates the sequence $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{starting with}\ n = 0~}}$:

$$
\underbrace{1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0}_{},\
\underbrace{1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0}_{},\ \underbrace{1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0}\ldots
$$

> because
>   $\ds{\sin\pars{\bracks{n + 1}\pi \over 3} =
> \sin\pars{\bracks{n + \color{#f00}{6} + 1}\pi \over 3} =
> \sin\pars{\bracks{n + 7}\pi \over 3}}$.

[image: Repeating Sequence]

Comment: Very nice presentation! (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks. $\left(\bullet\quad\bullet \atop {{\large \mid} \atop {\Large\smile}}\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>[Imported from a duplicate question]</sup>

[Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html) have the following representation:
$$ U_n(x)=\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{n-r}{r}(-1)^r (2x)^{n-2r} \tag{1}$$
hence the wanted sum is just $U_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, and since $\frac{1}{2}=\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$,
$$ U_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\sin((n+1)\pi/3)}{\sin(\pi/3)}.\tag{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer based upon a *transformation of generating series*.

> We show
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k-j}{j}(-1)^j
> =\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor k/3\rfloor}+(-1)^{\lfloor (k+1)/3\rfloor}}{2}
> \qquad\qquad k\geq 0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

where  $\lfloor x \rfloor$  denotes the *[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*. We set as upper limit of the sum $j=k$ and use $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $q>p$. We will also use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series.

> Note, the sum at the LHS of (1) is of the form
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k-j}{j}a_j
>   \end{align*}
>
> We can find in *[Riordan Array Proofs of Identities in Gould's Book](http://www.dsi.unifi.it/~resp/GouldBK.pdf)* by R. Sprugnoli in section 1.4 (A) a useful transformation formula:
>
> Let $A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jz^j$ be a series, then the following holds
>   \begin{align*}
>  \frac{1}{1-z}A\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z}\right)
>   =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k-j}{j}a_j\right)z^k
>   \end{align*}
>
> So, we have the following relationship
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^k]A(z)=a_k\qquad\longleftrightarrow\qquad
> [z^k]\frac{1}{1-z}A\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k-j}{j}a_j
> \tag{2}\end{align*}

We obtain from (1) with $a_j=(-1)^j$ the generating function $A(z)$
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-z)^j=\frac{1}{1+z}
\end{align*}

> and conclude according to (2)
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k-j}{j}(-1)^j&=[z^k]\frac{1}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z^2}{1-z}}\tag{3}\\
>   &=[z^k]\frac{1}{1-z+z^2}\tag{4}\\
>   &=[z^k]\left(1+z-z^3-z^4+z^6+z^7-z^9-z^{10}+\cdots\right)\tag{5}\\
>   &=\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor k/3\rfloor}+(-1)^{\lfloor (k+1)/3\rfloor}}{2}\tag{6}
>   \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply the transformation formula (2).
- In (4) we do some simplifications.
- In (5) we expand the series with the help of Wolfram Alpha.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $z^k$.

*Note:* This binomial identity can also be found as (1.75) in R. Sprugnoli's *[paper](http://www.dsi.unifi.it/~resp/GouldBK.pdf)*.